# how to update a row in datatables without table redraw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have dataTables v1.9.4 populated from a javascript array and i have checkbox column, which if it is `:checked` then the whole row should update every 5 seconds, the problem is that i have a large `fnRowCallback` function which is not execute after  row update thus all my row structure colapses. here is my update code:

```
function updateRow(){
    newRowData = $.data(document.body, 'updatedData');
    var newRow = [];
    newRow.push(1, 1);
    for (var title in newRowData[0]){
        newRow.push(newRowData[0][title]);
    }
    oTable.fnUpdate( newRow, updateIndex, false, true);
};
```

and this my `fnRowCallback` :

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                //make 3state button and indicator for relay mask & status
                $('td.relay', nRow).each(function(){
                    relayStatus = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html('<div class="hidden-value">' + relayStatus + '</div><div></div>');
                    if(relayStatus == 1){
                        $(this).children('div:last').addClass('relmas1');
                    }
                    if(relayStatus == 0){
                        $(this).children('div:last').addClass('relmas0');
                    }
                    if(relayStatus == -1){
                        $(this).children('div:last').addClass('relmas-1');
                    }
                });
                //makes update checkboxes
                var clientID = $('td.clientid', nRow).text();
                $('td.update', nRow).html('<input type="checkbox" data-clientid="' + clientID + '" />');
                //makes volumes
                var cuVol = parseInt($('td.volume', nRow).text(), 10)
                $('td.volume', nRow).html('<div class="volume-container"><div class="volume-tmp">' + cuVol + '</div><div class="volume-slider"></div></div>')
                $('td.volume div.volume-slider', nRow).slider({
                    value: cuVol,
                    range: "min",
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    slide: function( event, ui ) {
                        cuVol = ui.value;
                        $(this).siblings('div.volume-tmp').text(ui.value);
                    }
                });
            },
```

**the problem is :**
  how to redraw a single selected row with `fnRowCallback` without redraw the whole table and keep its checked state after redraw
**EDIT :**
I double checked my code and see that my code in being updated corectly but the problem is that my code is load in table in the way it is recieved via ajax not in the way i reorderd my table columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fnUpdate. Basically it works by row index and all values of the row must be inserted (can't enter 2 values when you have 4 columns for example)

Here is a link to the API of the method : [jQuery DataTable fnUpdate](http://datatables.net/ref#fnUpdate)

i think it triggers the row callback, but im not sure for it.

Comment: tnx for answer ur answer is almost correct and i solved it around 10 monthes before! but tnx it cansolve this

Comment: sorry, went through Unanswered, didnt see the date.